# How to get stdout of process?

Tags: bash, command-line, process, stdout

I started a process from the command line, but the window server died. However I see the process I started is still running. Is it possible to connect a terminal to the process to see its output?

This is the process:

```
ps -A | grep foo
73186 ??       4011:34.91 ./foo
```